# how to pass a Graph as parameter to a Method in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am new to Scala, and i want to Create a class for managing Graph Tasks.
So i want to pass a Graph object to my class as it's argument.
For example:

```
val graph = Graph(users, edges, nowhere)
users: RDD[(Long, String)],
edges: RDD[Edge(Long, Long, String)]
nowhere: String
```

and this my class

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.util.IntParam
// import classes required for using GraphX
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

class GraphAnalyzer(_graph: ???? ) {
  val graph:???? =_graph

  def GetVertecies(str: String): Long = {
    val nodesCount: Long =graph.vertices.count()
    nodesCount
  }
}
```

i don't know what should i do in "???" part of my class.
Can anyone help me for doing this?

Comment: `org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph` does not work?

Comment: Or just `Graph` since you already do `import org.apache.spark.graphx._`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

it's simple and IDE can help us. Eclipse showed me a tooltip. based on graph structure and it really depends on Graph vertices and edges.

i used the below type and it works:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.util.IntParam
// import classes required for using GraphX
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

class GraphAnalyzer(_graph: Graph[String, Int]  ) {
  val graph:Graph[String, Int]  =_graph

  def GetVertecies(): Long = {
    val nodesCount: Long = graph.vertices.count().toLong
    nodesCount*100
  }
}
```